# To display missing values [date] as range from Date Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have output as below

```
ID      Date 
Null    2012-10-01
1       2012-10-02
2       2012-10-03
NULL    2012-10-04
3       2012-10-05
NULL    2012-10-06
4       2012-10-07
NULL    2012-10-08
5       2012-10-10
NULL    2012-10-11
NULL    2012-10-12
6       2012-10-13
NULL   2012-10-16
```

As it has missing dates with value as NULL. I need to show final output as

```
2012-10-01 - 2012-10-01 (1 day )
2012-10-04 - 2012-10-04(1 day )
2012-10-06 - 2012-10-06(1 day )
2012-10-08 - 2012-10-08(1 day )
2012-10-11 - 2012-10-12(2 day )
2012-10-14 - 2012-10-14(1 day )
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: So you want date ranges for consecutive (sorted by date) **NULL** values of `ID` field, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the date ranges using the following query:

```
select
  min(date) as start,
  max(date) as end,
  datediff(max(date), min(date)) + 1 as numDays
from
  (select @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number, id, date
   from Table1 join (SELECT @curRow := 0) r where ID is null) T
group by
  datediff(date, '2012-10-01 00:00:00') - row_number;
```

The logic is based on a clever trick for grouping consecutive ranges.  First, we filter and number the rows in the subquery.  Then, the rows that are grouped together are found by comparing the number of days after `2012-10-01` to the row number.  If any rows share this value, then they must be consecutive, otherwise there would be a "jump" between two rows and the expression `datediff(date, '2012-10-01 00:00:00') - row_number` would no longer match.

Sample output ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4841d/23)):

```
START                           END                             NUMDAYS
October, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000  October, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000  1
October, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000  October, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000  1
October, 06 2012 00:00:00+0000  October, 06 2012 00:00:00+0000  1
October, 08 2012 00:00:00+0000  October, 08 2012 00:00:00+0000  1
October, 11 2012 00:00:00+0000  October, 12 2012 00:00:00+0000  2
October, 16 2012 00:00:00+0000  October, 16 2012 00:00:00+0000  1
```

From there I think it should be pretty trivial for you to get the exact output you are looking for.